# Leaflet JS - Create Map based on static png and draw markers

Tags: leaflet

I was able to generate map using tiles and draw marker

```
mymap = L.map('map').setView([0, 0], 2);
var panBounds = L.latLngBounds(L.latLng(-300, 300), L.latLng(300, -300));
var mapBounds = L.latLngBounds(L.latLng(180, 180), L.latLng(-180, -180));
var tileLayer = L.tileLayer(tileDirectory + "/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
attribution: "test",
maxZoom: 4,
minZoom: 2,
continuousWorld: false,
noWrap: true,
maxBoundsViscosity: 0.0,
bounds: mapBounds //render bound
}).addTo(mymap);
//set panning bounds
mymap.setMaxBounds(panBounds);
```

But I am looking for way to draw markers on top of static image instead of tile layers.  Is this possible with Leaflet JS

**Image overlay marker based on pixel co oordinates**

```
var w = 1366,
h = 768

let mymap = new L.Map('map', {
crs : L.CRS.Simple,
attributionControl: false,          
maxZoom: 4,
minZoom: 2,
zoom:2
}); 
var southWest = mymap.unproject(L.point(0, h), mymap.getMaxZoom());
var northEast = mymap.unproject(L.point(w, 0), mymap.getMaxZoom());
var bounds = new L.LatLngBounds(southWest, northEast);
L.imageOverlay(url, bounds).addTo(mymap);
mymap.fitBounds(bounds);

var m = {
                x: 692, 
                y: 287
        }
var marker = L.marker(mymap.unproject(L.point(m.x, m.y), 
mymap.getMaxZoom())).addTo(mymap);
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to add your image as an _Image Overlay_

Comment: This is explicitly covered in the [tutorial](http://leafletjs.com/examples.html) for `L.CRS.Simple`.

Comment: I was able to show map based on Image overlay .But adding markers to my static image do not come up correctly .

Comment: I have a floor image of 1366*768 px and i have location of each room on the floor by pixels . Ex: room 1 at (692*287) px How do I get correct marker                                                                                                     .

Comment: See http://leafletjs.com/examples/crs-simple/crs-simple.html#pixels-vs-map-units

Comment: I have checked this example but I did not get how bounds are calculated for  2315*2315 image used in example   var bounds = [[-26.5,-25], [1021.5,1023]];
var image = L.imageOverlay('uqm_map_full.png', bounds).addTo(map);    I have added my  updated code original post.